# Wine 1.7 not installing on Xubuntu 15.10

Tags: apt, xubuntu, wine, ppa

So, after setting up my installation of Xubuntu yesterday, I tried to install Wine 1.7 using ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa. However, after doing `sudo apt-get install wine1.7`, it keeps giving me this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-amd64 (= 1:1.7.44-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.44-0ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried several solutions that I've found online, such as autoremoving, adding the i386 architecture, cleaning up my packages, and fixing my apt-get installs. However, after trying all of the solutions that I could find, wine1.7 is still not installing. I'm not sure if this is my computer's fault or the ppa's fault, but if others could share their finds that would be great.

Thanks, Elly

As requested, here's the output for `apt-cache policy wine1.7 wine1.7-amd64 wine1.7-i386`:

```
wine1.7:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.7.44-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:1.7.44-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
wine1.7-amd64:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.7.44-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:1.7.44-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
wine1.7-i386:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.7.44-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:1.7.44-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ wily/main i386 Packages
```

and the output for `sudo apt-get install wine1.7-amd64 wine1.7-i386`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7-amd64 : Depends: libgphoto2-port10 (>= 2.5.2) but it is not installable
                 Recommends: libgnutls26 but it is not installable
                 Recommends: wine-gecko2.34 but it is not installable
                 Recommends: wine-mono4.5.4 but it is not installable
 wine1.7-i386:i386 : Depends: libgphoto2-port10:i386 (>= 2.5.2) but it is not installable
                     Recommends: libgnutls26:i386 but it is not installable
                     Recommends: libpcap0.8:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: wine-gecko2.34:i386 but it is not installable
                     Recommends: wine-mono4.5.4:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy wine1.7 wine1.7-amd64 wine1.7-i386`

Comment: @A.B. Edited the main post with the output.

Comment: Start `sudo apt-get install wine1.7-amd64 wine1.7-i386`

Comment: @A.B. Also edited into the main post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The needed packages are currently not available for Wily. Check [this filtered](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=wily) page.

Wait some days and the Wily packages are likely to be available. In the meantime, install the Vivid packages:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgphoto2/libgphoto2-port10_2.5.4-1.1ubuntu1_i386.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgphoto2/libgphoto2-port10_2.5.4-1.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgphoto2-port10*.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll try installing it again next week and I'll reply with how it goes.

Comment: Generally asking, is it possible to install older packages when I need them  urgently?

Comment: Small update. It's 2015-11-10 and the problem remains. According to launchpad, wine1.7 most recent build in the ppa is 11 weeks old; wily is younger than that.

Comment: Please, provide output of `find /etc/apt -name '*.list' -exec bash -c 'echo -e "\n$1\n"; cat -n "$1"' _ '{}' \;`

Comment: The packages from the wine-ubuntu ppa have not been updated regularly because one of the developers has been occupied by his day job, while the other one's computer is not working.

Comment: More than one month has passed and this, for some reason accepted answer, still didn't become useful...

Comment: @user1182474 I'm not the maintainer of the PPA feel free to downvote the answer.

Answer (score 10):

The dependency it fails on is `libgphoto2-port10`, which isn't Wily. You can try manually installing the DEB files from Trusty:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libgphoto2-port10

Comment: This is the solution, thank you very much! I have just went by this link, downloaded the libgphoto2-port10_2.5.3.1-1ubuntu2_i386.deb package, clicked to install it and the problem is gone.  @elly consider marking this answer as the solution perhaps, we have already been waiting enough (following the A.B.'s recommendation) to get nothing, D.B.'s solution is much more practical.

Comment: You should also consider the wine-staging package.  I find that it is usually more up to date than the wine1.7 package/ppa

Comment: This worked for me as well, dlded both packages

Comment: [Wily 64 bit version](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/189057836/libgphoto2-port10_2.5.4-1.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb) and [Wily 32 bit version](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/189057849/libgphoto2-port10_2.5.4-1.1ubuntu1_i386.deb)

Answer (score 4):

You still can use [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com) on (X)Ubuntu 15.10.

With PlayOnLinux you create (and safe remove) 'virtual drives' (in  /home/{user}/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/ ) with different Wine versions and different settings.

It's in 15.10 repository:

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

In the program: Menu -> Tools -> Manage Wine Versions

You can install Wine versions (x86 or x64) you need, including 1.7 (latest 1.7.54), and then use in 'virtual drives'.

Programs from PlayOnLinux 'virtual drives' you can run like this:

```
/usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "Evernote.5.8.13"
```

And, of course, you can add .desktop entry in /home/{user}/.local/share/applications/

Imho, it's more convenient than pure Wine anyway.

Comment: Op wanted wine1.7 PlayOnLinux is just a wine wrapper that still uses wine 1.6

Comment: In PlayOnLinux you can use Wine version you choose for particular 'virtual drive'. And it can install 1.7 on 15.10, even though `apt-get install wine1.7` fails as described above.

Answer (score 2):

Since Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily Werewolf) and Debian 8, you can install the package `wine-development,` without needing any additional ppa's, which installs the latest development version.

Once installed, the following executables will be available:
`wine-development, winecfg-development,` etc; instead of the traditionals `wine, winecfg,` etc.

## Update

Wine 1.8 and 1.9 have been released; and are available for Ubuntu 15.10 Wily Werewolf. To install them, you can add a new ppa created by the wine theam:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
```

For more information, you can take a look at the [Ubuntu section on the Official Wine Wiki](http://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need the very latest version of Wine you can always just do:

```
sudo apt-get install wine winetricks
```

Comment: `wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed`

Answer (score 0):

If wine installation fails with broken dependencies like

```
wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed
```

and attempts to install `wine1.6`, reveal that it depends on `libgphoto2-6:i386`, which then appears to depend on non-installable `libgphoto2-port10:i386`, and an attempt to install `libgphoto2-port10:i386` would remove the AMD64 version along with `libsane` and some other packages, then you likely have disabled "*Recommended updates*" in Software Sources configuration (e.g. I had only "*Important security updates*" checked and everything else unchecked).

Once I've re-enabled "*Recommended updates*", I've successfully installed wine.