# Can't install wine1.7 on Ubuntu 15.10 due to a broken dependencies

Tags: wine

There's a broken dependencies:

```
balthild@Balthild-Linux:~$ sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
[sudo] password for balthild: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-amd64 (= 1:1.7.44-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.44-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
           Recommends: gnome-exe-thumbnailer but it is not going to be installed or
                       kde-runtime but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-horai-umefont but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-unfonts-core but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-wqy-microhei
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And I then find the reason:

```
balthild@Balthild-Linux:~$ sudo apt-get install wine1.7-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7-amd64 : Depends: libgphoto2-port10 (>= 2.5.2) but it is not installable
                 Depends: wine1.7:any (= 1:1.7.44-0ubuntu1)
                 Recommends: libcapi20-3 but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: libgnutls26 but it is not installable
                 Recommends: libosmesa6 but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: unixodbc but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: wine-gecko2.34 but it is not installable
                 Recommends: wine-mono4.5.4 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The package `libgphoto2-port10` is no longer provided in 15.10 wily, and instead there's `libgphoto2-port12` .

```
balthild@Balthild-Linux:~$ sudo apt-get install libgphoto2-port12
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgphoto2-port12 is already the newest version.
```

With this, iI can't install wine1.7 on my system. Is there any resolutions?

Comment: Duplicate of  http://askubuntu.com/questions/689034/wine-1-7-not-installing-on-xubuntu-15-10
Looks like Wine is  not correctly Packaged for 15.10 Release Cycle. I have never had any issues with the packages for 15.04 using the same PPA.

Comment: @RajatPandita yes, could be a duplicate but not really. The given answer seems to solve this problem and looks promising.

Comment: Please look deeper into the post, There is one Dependency libgphoto2-port10 If you install this manually as per http://askubuntu.com/questions/689034/wine-1-7-not-installing-on-xubuntu-15-10 It should work. Let me know if it does not.

Answer (score 0):

You install Wine 1.6 first then install wine 1.7 though play on Linux

Open up a terminal and type in:

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.6
```

Install play on Linux

Download the latest version of play on Linux.

```
wget https://www.playonlinux.com/script_files/PlayOnLinux/4.2.9/PlayOnLinux_4.2.9.deb
```

Then install it.

```
sudo dpkg -i PlayOnLinux_4.2.9.deb
```

Open play on linux

```
playonlinux
```

Click then configure then click on <kbd>New</kbd> to create a new Virtual Drive

[image]

When you have done that. Click on your virtual Drive that you just created:
[image]

Select the wine version you want installed then click on the <kbd>></kbd> to install the wine version.

[image]

When the wine version is installed it should show up like this.

[image]

To run applications using wine 1.7 click on configure and then click on a virtual Drive 
[image]
Change wine version from `system` to `1.7`

Comment: Looks promising. Great idea.