# Installing Wine reveals unmet dependencies

Tags: command-line, wine, 15.10

#### First things first

I am very sorry if this is a duplicate, but frankly I've tried reading many other answers and I don't understand half of it. I'm still very much a noob when it comes to Ubuntu and I just need someone to look at my situation and tell me what to do to fix it.

#### What I Want to Do

I want to install the latest stable version of Wine.

#### What I Did

1. Googled `install wine`.
2. Selected the [2<sup>nd</sup> result](https://www.linux.com/community/blogs/128-desktops/805164-wine-1735-released-how-to-install-on-ubuntudebianlinux-mint), also being the one previewed by Google's instant results feature.
3. Did the things instructed.

#### Terminal output

```
coronet@Coronet:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
[sudo] password for coronet: 
 Welcome to the Wine Team PPA.  Here you can get the latest available Wine betas for every supported version of Ubuntu.  This PPA is managed by Scott Ritchie and Maarten Lankhorst.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpdk5nhr27/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpdk5nhr27/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key F9CB8DB0 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpdk5nhr27/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key F9CB8DB0: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ubuntu Wine Team" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
coronet@Coronet:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily InRelease                                    
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security InRelease [65.9 kB]             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily InRelease                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily Release.gpg                                  
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main Sources [44.1 kB]          
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted Sources [2,854 B]    
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe Sources [11.2 kB]      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily Release                                      
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse Sources [2,788 B]    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main amd64 Packages                          
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main amd64 Packages [141 kB]    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main i386 Packages                           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main Translation-en                          
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted amd64 Packages [10.9 kB]
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_GB                         
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe amd64 Packages [50.2 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [6,247 B]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main i386 Packages [137 kB]    
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted i386 Packages [10.8 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe i386 Packages [50.2 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse i386 Packages [6,443 B]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily InRelease                                
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main Translation-en               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse Translation-en         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted Translation-en         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe Translation-en           
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main amd64 Packages                          
  404  Not Found
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports InRelease                      
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main i386 Packages                           
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main Translation-en_US                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main Translation-en                          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main Translation-en_GB                       
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main Sources [72.7 kB]        
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Sources [3,741 B]  
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Sources [21.5 kB]    
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Sources [3,199 B]  
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main amd64 Packages [204 kB]  
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [13.3 kB]
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe amd64 Packages [89.3 kB]
Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [6,247 B]
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main i386 Packages [201 kB]   
Get:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted i386 Packages [13.4 kB]
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe i386 Packages [86.7 kB]
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [6,678 B]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted Sources             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse Sources             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted amd64 Packages      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted i386 Packages       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse i386 Packages       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Sources                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Sources                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe Sources                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Sources                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main amd64 Packages                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted amd64 Packages                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe amd64 Packages                  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse amd64 Packages                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main i386 Packages                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted i386 Packages                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe i386 Packages                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse i386 Packages                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Translation-en                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Translation-en_GB                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Translation-en                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Translation-en_GB             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Translation-en                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Translation-en_GB             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe Translation-en                  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe Translation-en_GB               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main Translation-en              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Translation-en        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Translation-en        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Translation-en          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main Sources                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe Sources               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main amd64 Packages            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe amd64 Packages        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main Translation-en            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe Translation-en        
Fetched 1,326 kB in 1min 11s (18.7 kB/s)                                       
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/calibre2/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/calibre2/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
coronet@Coronet:~$ sudo apt-get install -y wine1.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-amd64 (= 1:1.7.44-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.44-0ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Deeply sorry if the formatting for the terminal output is so horrendous. I really tried my best, and I just could not figure out how to do a multi-line code block that didn't show `the annoying background fill across multiple lines because that sort of thing isn't really something I want to see in any other context than text taking up less than a line.`

Comment: Highlight the text you want to format and press `ctrl`+`k` to block format it.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and then try again. Edit your post to include any errors.

Comment: Try to follow the steps outlined [in this *question*](http://askubuntu.com/q/689034/380067) (yes, in the *question*); then, if you get the same errors as in the question, try to follow [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/691290/380067) answer.

Comment: Also I recommend using these instructions to get the latest version: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Comment: Since Wine 1.8 has been released, WIne 1.7 should not be used anymore. Try installing `wine1.8`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to install wine1.8
Turns out there was a package called gphoto10 that needed to be installed, which wasn't part of the dependency list (gphoto12 was the install candidate).
I had to download gphoto10 separately, search for it here ... packages.ubuntu.com, download the deb file and install the deb file (install the gdebi package to help you). Then i was able to install wine