# My ubuntu 15.10 packages uninstalled accidentally . How to get them back again?

Tags: wine, 15.10, uninstall

I am new to ubuntu and I was trying to install wine1.7 in ubuntu 15.10. I was following this link from the ubuntu forum while facing problems in installing ubuntu...

[Wine 1.7 not installing on Xubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689034/wine-1-7-not-installing-on-xubuntu-15)

[image]

As well as I reached to the 4th instruction sudo apt-get install -f ... I saw it's removing all packages from the ubuntu ... I didn't even get time to stop it and it removed all packages from my ubuntu ... I don't even have terminal in ubuntu and I don't have unity dash bar and I am not able to do anything in ubuntu just open the desktop and don't have anything ... what should I do to get all the packages?